# flask server not working as expected locally

Tags: python, flask, post, python-requests, localhost

I made a simple flask server and it worked pretty fine on heroku, but when I try to run the server locally, error 400 (Bad Request) will occur. Also on the flask output, I get some weird characters. This is a sample of what I made:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/controller', methods=['POST'])
def controller():
   return "1"

@app.route('/player', methods=['POST'])
def player():
   return "5"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = 'localhost', debug = True, port = 8080)
```

and this is the output of the flask server with an empty POST request:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2020 12:32:25] code 400, message Bad request version ('Ôù\x90\x88\x9fb07')
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2020 12:32:25] "[35m[1m  ü­AîKîeÌ²}kÔùb07[0m" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

I am using the requests library to make the POST request

Answer (score 0):

Your example works like a charm on my machine.

How do you create a **POST** request? Maybe that is the problem.

Please try:

```
~/Tests/stackoverflow via  v3.8.4 (venv) 
❯ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/controller
1
```

Comment: somehow it worked with your method, but I don't see why requests library doesn't work locally but works when running the code on heroku

Comment: For a starter, you could show us what you tried. Please copy the complete request code.

Comment: ```print(requests.post("http://localhost:8080/controller", json={"foo": 1}).json())```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import flask
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/controller', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def controller():
   return "1"

@app.route('/player', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def player():
   return "5"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = 'localhost', debug = True, port = 8080)
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use GET requests. the new import line didn't make any difference for me